# check if files have been changed with Subversion svn

Tags: svn, changelist

I'm using Subversion svn under windows in cmd.
How can I check which files have been changed from the revision before? I tried

```
 svn.exe info --changelist xx   # xx is a revision number
```

But there is no output.
I guess I need to add the url to the trunk + I need to tell svn.exe that I want the changelist from the current revision I have on my computer (e.g. 74) to the newest (e.g. 75).
How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) command.

```
svn status  # By itself, it'll show you local changes in your working copy
svn status --show-updates  # This will show what's out of date
```

Also, if you're using Windows I heartily recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: TortoiseSVN recommendation seconded! (And Tortoise(Git|CVS|Hg|Bzr) too)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you just want `svn status`, which will give you a list of all of the current changes in your repository. You can also use `svn diff`, which will show you a detailed diff of all of the current changes. If you want to diff between two different changelists, `svn diff` also can show you this information in a variety of different ways. See `svn help diff` or [the online documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) for more information.