# How to check if a file is changed in svn and decide the next action based on it in a script

Tags: bash, svn

I want to write a bash script That if a file is changed then I commit.
is there a command that returns true or false so That I can check it in my "If the file is changed?"

I have:

if ???

svn --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MYUSERNAME --password MYPASSWORD commit . -m "MY COMMENT"`;

I created a .sh file and here is the content just to test what svn status is returning and even if there is no change to the file it returns "$SVNST is NOT empty":

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
SVNST=$`svn status MYFILE`
echo $SVNST
if [ -z "$SVNST" ]
then
      echo "\$SVNST is empty"
else
      echo "\$SVNST is NOT empty"
fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if files have been changed with Subversion svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343522/check-if-files-have-been-changed-with-subversion-svn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `$` before the `svn` invocation, which results in your `-z` zero check always being false, because there is always that `$` at the beginning of `$SVNST`. Change:

```
SVNST=$`svn status MYFILE`
```

to:

```
SVNST=`svn status MYFILE`
```

and your script will work as you intended it.